# Whitelabel Error Page Tomcat + Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

В общем проблема такая.

Развернул war на Tomcat 9. /login, /index /403 отрабатывают, а другие к примеру /convert выдает Writable error.

При запуске локально апликации спринга, отрабатывает все хорошо, но при развертывании получают такие ошибки. В самом war, вроде как присутствуют нужные страницы, классы.

В чем может быть причина?

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.iga</groupId>
    <artifactId>trends</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>trends</name>
    <description>test</description>



    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>com.iga.trends.TrendsApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>


        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>4.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- наш старый добрый thymeleaf шаблонизатор -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- опционально, библиотека добавит полезные теги для SPRING SECURITY в Thymeleaf шаблонах -->

        <!-- содержит в себе необходимые библиотеки для создания ВЕБ приложения -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- горячая подмена, выключенный кеш для шаблонов, включенный live reload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <finalName>app</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Поменял:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/convert"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView convert(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("convert");
        mav.addObject("alarms", storageService.loadAll().map( Path::getFileName)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        mav.addObject("toks", storageService.loadAllToks().map( Path::getFileName)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        mav.addObject("naprs", storageService.loadAllNaprs().map( Path::getFileName)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        return mav;
    }
```

На

```
    @GetMapping(value = {"/convert"})
    public String convert(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("alarms", storageService.loadAll().map( Path::getFileName)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        return "convert";
    }
```

Развернутое приложение на Tomcate теперь отпрабатывает по этому запросу нормально.
Может кто-то подсказать в чем проблема?

Comment: "И развернутое приложение в Tomcat отрабатывать нормально." В чём проблема?
"Локально не на томкэте работает нормально..." А на чём?
И stacktrace ошибки приложите.

Comment: @Bakhuss
Немного запутался. 

В общем на томкэте при запросе /convert вылетает Whitelabel Error Page (404 - я так понимаю не находит convert.html ), в мавене локально, при старте аплиакции таких проблем нет. 

в контроллере, поменял  ModelAndView на Model  (где обрабатывается /convert)  - и все заработало.